# How to write 'must do... then...'

Tags: grammar

hopefully this is just a quick one!

I'm wondering how one would say a sentence like 'You must take off your shoes then, put them in the basket'. I know

> 靴を脱がなければなりません
> バスケットに置きます

could be used for each part separately. But, how would you combine these? Would you use the negative te-form of なる then add から？i.e.

> 靴を脱がなければならないでから、バスケットに置きま

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint:  The "must" in your English sentence does not just apply to the first verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> 靴を脱いでバスケットに入れなければなりません。

Or you can add から and say (although this is not necessary):

> 靴を脱いでからバスケットに入れなければなりません。

I hope you understand how this works. Simply treat 靴を脱ぐ and バスケットに入れる as a paired action combined with the te-form.